# Xamarin: What am I supposed to assign to "context"?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Ive got this bit of code

```csharp
public void TestGPS()
{
    Context context;
    var locationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
    locationManager.AddTestProvider("Test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
    locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled("Test", true);
}
```

Now, I cant debug my code, since the compiler marks context as "unassigned". 
But what would i assign context to?

THanks! :)

Comment: You are not supposed to assign it, you receive context from outside. There is always a context somewhere around, you pick the correct one to use. E.g. it might be your activity or your fragment, or even [Application.Context](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11102/what-is-equivalent-to-getapplicationcontext-in-xamarin-android).

Comment: o okay.... so what would recommend changing in my code? thanks!

Comment: You pick the context that is better for that method and pass it as a parameter (if the method is somewhere unrelated), or use the hosting activity/fragment as context directly (if the method is inside an activity/fragment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing/requiring `Context` is very common in Android.

Usually that means you have to pass reference to current activity. That will be `this` inside any activity, `this.Context` inside fragment.

If you want to use this code inside some service that has no clue about UI/activities, common suggestion is to pass context to the service initialization and then store a reference to this context. Be careful as this might lead to memory leaks (you will be storing a reference to an activity and will be keeping it alive).

Alternatively, you can use so called current context: `Android.App.Application.Context`.

In your case, if this is a part of Activity code, you have to change it to:

```
public void TestGPS()
{
    var locationManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
    locationManager.AddTestProvider("Test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
    locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled("Test", true);
}
```

If this is a part of a service (non-UI), then:

```
public void TestGPS()
{
    var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
    var locationManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
    locationManager.AddTestProvider("Test", false, false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
    locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled("Test", true);
}
```

Some good articles on the topic:

[Xamarin: Android Activities, Context, Intents and Views](https://dzone.com/articles/xamarin-android-activities)

[What is Context on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-on-android)